# Mean Value Inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am working through an Algebra book, and am having trouble understanding exactly how

$$
q(x^p-1) - p(x^q-1) >< 0
$$

is equivalent to

$$
(x-1)[q(x^{p-1} + x^{p-2} + ... + 1)-p(x^{q-1} + x^{q-2} +...+1)] >< 0
$$

I am probably missing a simple detail, but I can't seem to work out the equivalence of these two statements. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is $><$ equivalent to $\neq$?

Comment: @Axoren I would assume so; "greater than or less than" and "not equal to" are almost the same thing...

Comment: Hint: each of the two series in parentheses in your second expression is a finite geometric series.

Comment: @K.Jiang Wasn't sure if it was some other relation. Normally, I've witnessed $<>$ for "lesser or greater", but no once the reverse. Could have been an attempt at a bowtie or something: $\bowtie$

Comment: Yeah, it is definitely easier to just use the "not equal to" sign, so I'm not really sure.

Comment: Yes I am using George Chrystal's book which was written at the turn of the last century.  Occaisonally I have had to search for a symbol in __A History of Mathematical Notations__, but all in all I think its a great book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $x=1$ is a root of the equation $x^n-1=0$.

Hence, by the [factor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem), $(x-1)$ divides $(x^n-1)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Also, it is noted that the sum of the a [geometric](http://mathematics.laerd.com/maths/geometric-progression-intro.php) [progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) with first term $a$, common ratio $r$ and number of terms $n$ has its sum as follows:
$$a+ar+ar^2+\ldots +ar^{n-1}=a\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$$

Now if $a=1$ and $r=x$ and $n=p$ or $q$, as may be the case, then you get
$$1+x+x^2+\ldots +x^{p-2}+x^{p-1}=\frac{x^p-1}{x-1}$$
And $$1+x+x^2+\ldots +x^{q-2}+x^{q-1}=\frac{x^q-1}{x-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: All that was done was a factoring out of an $x - 1$ term. The factoring is definitely valid;
$$x^{n} - 1 = (x - 1)(x^{n - 1} + x^{n - 2} + ... + 1).$$

Make sure you see why this is true!